# ¿Cómo aplicar las nuevas configuraciones de dependencia de Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Acabo de actualizar Android Studio y recibí **varias advertencias** diciendo que las siguientes configuraciones habían cambiado:

- `compile`
- `provided`
- `apk`

Los mensajes de advertencia eran como este:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Después de leer [lo que dice este enlace](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html), corregí (o eso creo) mi archivo `gradle` del siguiente modo:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionName '1.3 (beta)'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 1
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Luego de actualizar el archivo, la app compila sin errores y casi todas las advertencias desaparecieron, menos una:

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'.

La advertencia me envía hacia el archivo `build.gradle`  de la carpeta `app` (el que he compartido más arriba).  Como pueden ver, he cambiado todos los `compile` por `implementation`. Actualmente, la palabra *compile* aparece solamente aquí: `compileSdkVersion 26` ... he intentando a cambiarlo por `implementationSdkVersion 26`  y por `apiSdkVersion 26`. En ambos casos da error.

Como ya dije, la app funciona, pero tengo siempre esa molesta advertencia y quisiera saber lo que habría que hacer para quitarla.

Comment: Una sugerencia, que no tiene nada que ver con el problema, yo establezco  versión de compilación a 27 ya que es Android 8.1 y está fuera de beta, algunas librerías actualizadas me mostraban warnings ya que tenían establecido una versión superior de compilación.

Comment: @Webserveis sinceramente yo no termino de aclararme con eso de las versiones en Android... supongo que al no coincidir te daba los Warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema, haciendo lo indicado [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586312/5587982).

Pongo aquí lo que he hecho, por si le puede servir a alguien en un futuro:

Se trataba de cambiar lo siguiente en el apartado `dependencies`  del archivo **`build.gradle` del proyecto**, (el general), no el de la app:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

por

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Con esto la advertencia ha desparecido.

La cuestión es cambiar la versión de `google-services` de la `3.1.1` (u otra inferior que puedas tener), a la versión `3.2.0` (u otra superior, cuando éstas existan en un futuro).