# Diferencia de usar api o implementation en las dependencias de Android en Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Al actualizar Android studio a la nueva versión `3.1.1` el mismo me ha indicado que debía cambiar cosas en las dependencias `compile` por `implementation` he subido la versión de compilación a 27...

Pero gradle al realizar build me devuelve el error:

> Android dependency 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout'
>   has different version for the compile (1.0.2) and runtime (1.1.0)
>   classpath. You should manually set the same version via
>   DependencyResolution

He reiniciado la cache con `(File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart).` pero aun sigue dando el error

De todos los módulos que uso, solo uno usa `constraint-layout` y lo tengo en
`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'` en principio debería estar bien establecido.

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime) he encontrado la recomendación de usar `api` antes que `implementation`

de la siguiente manera

```
api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

Y se ha solucionado misteriosamente...

Mi duda es
¿Cual es la diferencia en usar `implementation` o `api` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mi me ocurrió algo parecido a lo tuyo<sup>1</sup>, así que estuve leyendo el apartado [Usar las nuevas configuraciones de dependencias](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio#new_configurations) de la documentación de Android.

Allí explican la diferencia (las negritas son mías):

> ### `implementation`
>
> La dependencia está disponible en el momento de la compilación para
>   el  módulo y solo en el tiempo de ejecución para el consumidor del
>   módulo.  **Para compilaciones grandes que abarcan varios proyectos, el
>   uso de `implementation` en lugar de `api` o `compile` puede generar
>   mejoras importantes en el tiempo de compilación**, ya que reduce la
>   cantidad de  proyectos que el sistema de compilación debe volver a
>   compilar. **La  mayoría de los módulos de apps y de prueba deben usar
>   esta  configuración**.

---

> ### `api`
>
> La dependencia está disponible para el módulo en el momento de la
>   compilación, y también está disponible para el consumidor del módulo
>   en el momento de la compilación y en el tiempo de ejecución. Esta
>   configuración tiene el mismo comportamiento que `compile` (que ahora es
>   obsoleta) y **normalmente deberías usarla solo en los módulos de la
>   biblioteca**. Los módulos de la app deben usar `implementation`, a menos
>   que desees exponer su API a otro módulo de prueba.
>
> Como en el caso de las versiones estables actuales del complemento de
>   Android, las configuraciones anteriores están disponibles para
>   dependencias de clases o tipos de compilación específicas. Por
>   ejemplo, puedes usar `api` para que la dependencia esté disponible
>   para todas las variantes, o bien `redApi` para que esté disponible
>   únicamente para las variantes red del módulo.
>
> ---

Y finalmente, una nota:

> Nota: `compile`, `provided` y `apk` siguen estando disponibles. Sin
>   embargo, desaparecerán en la próxima versión importante del
>   complemento de Android.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cómo aplicar las nuevas configuraciones de dependencia de Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156016/29967)</sub>