# ¿como puedo hacer la conexión de mi login en android studio con una BD en xampp?

Tags: android, android-studio, xampp

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android Studio y al hacer el login me he estado guiando por varios tutoriales en Internet y textos, todo marcha bien hasta que me pide que realice las dependencias para conectar con la base de datos en **xampp** haciendo uso de `compile "com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0"` dentro de `build.gradle(Module: app)` , en este punto me arroja un error al sincronizar y este me dice que el método ya esta obsoleto y que en cambio haga uso del **API** indicada https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies?utm_source=android-studio#dependency_configurations , pero la verdad no entiendo como hacerlo y por mas que e consultado no encuentro ejemplos de este método ¿alguien me puede decir por favor cual es la manera correcta de solucionar esto y como puedo solucionar este problema?

```
dependencies { 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3' 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' 
    compile "com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En las nuevas configuraciones de gradle `compile` quedó obsoleto, y debe ser cambiado por `implementation`.

Por lo tanto, tienes que cambiar `compile` por `implementation` en esta línea:

```
compile "com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0"
```

De paso, actualiza tu versión de Volley a la más reciente, quedando así:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Para más detalles puedes ver las siguientes preguntas y sus respuestas:

- [Diferencia de usar api o implementation en las dependencias de Android en Gradle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158394/29967)
- [¿Cómo aplicar las nuevas configuraciones de dependencia de Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156016/29967)