# Error al querer ingresar a la App

Tags: java, android, firebase

El Logcat me arroja este error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matias.finalcode, PID: 9952
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.matias.finalcode.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:91)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9952 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Y este es el código que da error según el Logcat...

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InicioActivity.class);
                                    //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LookingService.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                            }
                        }
            });
```

Qué puede ser?...

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, ojalá puedan ayudarme. Saludos!

Comment: Tendrías que comprobar que `email` y `password` no son nulos. Y también tendrías que comprobar que tienes `Firebase` bien configurado. Dinos también en qué método de tu `Activity` usas ese código.

Comment: @A.Cedano es raro porque ese mismo código lo usaba hace un mes y funcionaba... Estuve retirado un mes por algunos motivos y ahora que vuelvo me larga ese error.

Comment: Nadie sabe si algo se desconfiguró. Empieza por lo más elemental, depurando las variables `email` y `password`, luego revisando si realmente tu `Firebase` está funcionando bien en la App y revisa también en la consola de `Firebase` si tu proyecto sigue activo allí. Ah, y antes de todo eso, actualiza Android Studio, [han habido cambios importantes últimamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156016/29967).

Comment: Haz todas las actualizaciones que te indique tu IDE (supongo que usas Android Studio)  y en el `gradle` actualiza [todas las librerías de `Firebase` que estés usando a sus últimas versiones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419#available_libraries). Cuando actualices el IDE es posible que te de un montón de WARNING o de ERRORES, porque han declarado `compile`  obsoleto... podrás resolverlo modificando el `gradle` más o menos como indico en la pregunta/respuesta enlazada en mi comentario anterior.

Comment: @A.Cedano al parecer si eran los compile, porque los modifique y ahora funciona como debería el código. Muchas gracias amigo, que estés bien!