# Android Firebase

Tags: firebase

Estoy comenzando con Android Studio 3.1
He creado un proyecto en console.firebase.google. Para crear una base de datos en tiempo real, mediante Firebase.
Seguí todos los pasos que se indican: 1 Registrar app 2 Descarga de archivos  3 Agregar el SDK de Firebase

Agregue dependencias, plugin, etc.
También, en SDK Tools active: Google Play services.
Google Repository estaba ya activo.
Despues dí clic en Sync.

En la ventana inferior apareció un warning, que dice:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
 It will be removed at the end of 2018.

Para solucionar el Warning, busque en la web la solución.
 Encontré que hay varios desarrolladores que tienen el mismo problema. Inclusive en esta misma web pero en inglés.
Algunos indican que lo han solucionado otros indican que no.

Cambié de compile a implementation.  Pero da error la línea de código ...firebase-database.
Sé que esa línea da error porque si la comento (//) dejan de aparecer los errores.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database: 15.0.0'  //Esta línea  da error
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Y es la que necesito utilizar para poder trabajar con Bases de Datos.

He leído ya varias veces los procedimientos en  https://firebase.google.com/  pero sin resultados.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea desde ya gracias.

Comment: no veo problema alguno en tu importacion, solo quita el espacio que hay entre `: 15.0.0`, ese error no te deja hacer el gradle? o solo te aparece subrayado y te deja compilar?, si es el caso de la dos es un detallito que lleva arrastrando desd ela version Studio 2.1, lo cual te marcaba ese detalle porque segun existia una version mas estable

Comment: Oooh   que torpe soy!!    Muchas Gracias Miguel. Trate de buscar por medio del Centro de Ayuda / ¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas? Pero no encuentro la marca al lado de la respuesta   ¿¡¡?

Comment: Yo tengo `Firebase` en mi proyecto y tuve los mismos Warning que tu, lo único diferente en tu gradle  es lo que ya te comentó @MiguelOsorio, el espacio en blanco. Sin embargo, yo seguía teniendo un Warning que se resuelve actualizando la versión del classpath de google-services, en el gradle del proyecto, [te dejo aquí la pregunta y la solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156016/29967), por si sigues teniendo ese Warning, luego de haber resuelto lo de `Firebase`.

Comment: Ya no lo tengo. Lo corregí gracias al comentario de Miguel Osorio.